# Grouping UNIONed Cypher Results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query like this that works fine:

```
MATCH path = (start)-[]-(some)-[]-(path)-[]-(end)
RETURN start, end, path
UNION
MATCH path = (start)-[]-(some)-[]-(other)-[]-(path)-[]-(end)
RETURN start, end, path
```

The only problem is that in some cases the same `start` and `end` nodes may match both patterns resulting in duplicates (with respect to `start` and `end`). Is there a cypher way to

`RETURN DISTINCT start, end, COLLECT(path)`

for the result of a UNION? Something like a SQL subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't collect over multiple `RETURN` in a `UNION`. There is an open issue on GitHub requesting something similar: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725

If start and end matter, you could `MATCH` them first and then try to `MATCH` the different paths:

```
MATCH (start), (end)
// try to match the different paths
OPTIONAL MATCH path_a = (start)-[]-(some)-[]-(path)-[]-(end)
OPTIONAL MATCH path_b = (start)-[]-(some)-[]-(other)-[]-(path)-[]-(end)
RETURN DISTINCT start, end, path_a, path_b
```

Not sure if that would work in you case, but it would give you one result row for each pair of start/end.